# Execution failed for task ':app: compileDebugKotlin'. In flutter after using firebase_dynamic_links:

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, mobile, firebase-dynamic-links

[image]

I am getting this error after adding " firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.4.8" ths pacakage in my fluttr app

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

this is the kotln version I have used

I was expecting to run the program

Comment: As error says you need to upgrade the kotlin gradle plugin. try it with 1.9.10 or newer

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading to the latest Kotlin version did not work, upgrading to another Kotlin version did. I changed the Kotlin version `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'` and it worked for me. You also can check different Kotlin versions.